# Spring Data get last page as first with Sort and Pageable

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a chart in my app and need to get data with pagination, but the problem is X-axis on the chart is a time. I need to sort data by ascending (from old event to new), first of all, I need to return the last page (rewound pagination to end).

For that, I get the number of pages and send it to `Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> s, Pageable p);` with the last page number.

```
Pageable pagination = PageRequest.of(getLastPageNumber(), // count(*) where ...
                                     filter.getPageSize(), 
                                     Sort.by("time").ascending());
// specification not empty it has 5 independent where conditions wired to user interface
repository.findAll(Specification.where(specification), pagination);
```

Problems:

1. The latest page is not filled completely. If we have 500 elements on-page, and 501 in the database, implementation like this returns 1 element. Because we get residue.
2. We always need to know how many elements are in the table. Select from the big table (≃1_000_000 rows) with bunch conditions in the `Specification` object, not the light operation itself, + addition queries with `count` which contain the same `where` conditions as well as into the target `Specification`, not affecting performance positively.

Can I somehow get the last page as a first? It's similar to `findTop` with the saving ability to use spring data pagination. I can't use `findTop` directly because had too many filters if it is possible I want to stay with a Specification-based solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about simply reversing the sort order i.e. use `Sort.by("time").descending()`?

Comment: because I got elements from earlier to the latest but the chart should work from latest to earlier. But I can just sort after fetch. That is an idea!